# Is Joining large table with small table in MySQL can affect query performance?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to ask if this will not affect query performance,for example in MySQL db, I have this two tables.

tblA = 20,000 rows
tblB = 10 rows

```
 select A.emp_code,A.emp_fname,A.emp_status,A.emp_position 
  from tblA A
  inner join tblB B
  on A.emp_code = B.empcode
  where A.emp_code = '013777'
  order by A.emp_code desc
LIMIT 0,1
```

Does my query will not slow for joining with large table and small table ?

Answer (score 0):

Joins in general need more resources, but is the result what matters, then you can take in mind [Optimizing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb.html) and start by your tables design and queries... for that I can suggest using indexes for: `A.emp_code` and `B.empcode` if any doesn't have it

Comment: yes they are in indexed,but the query time gets 6 secs.

Comment: Is really necessary the `LIMIT` clause? And the used join is to verify `empcode` exists in `table B` or for another reason?

Comment: Joining a single table, especially one with only 6 rows (assuming the rows aren't huge text files or blobs) might add a thousandth of a second or so. You really want to try run "explain *your query*". Also try run it without the join - the obvious solution would be to index A.emp_code but it's always worth doing a little research first.